# How to return a two-dimensional pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers

As the title suggests, how to return pointer like this:

```
xxxxxxx foo() {

    static int arr[5][5];
    return arr;
}
```

BTW. I know that I must specify the size of one dimension at least, but how?

Comment: A better question is _why_ you would want to return one. I honestly cannot think of any manner of program design where that makes sense.

Comment: @Lundin Maybe a data-processing function which returns a pointer to a 2d array.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you would need to return such a pointer, rather than use a pointer passed as one of the function's parameters, which is the convention in C. Returning pointers from functions is most often a clear indication of a bad program design.

Comment: @Lundin You're right. I know it's very convenient to return multiple values using that method. But I think it's natural to return a pointer directly if there isn't any other return value. Why is that a bad program design? Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: @Lundin well. Do you mean that the return value should be an error code instead of a pointer?

Comment: Think of it: what could this pointer point at? It could point at a local variable (blatant bug), it could point at dynamic data (poor design), it could point at statics/globals (poor design and not thread-safe), or it could point at one of the passed parameters (pointless).

Comment: @Lundin I know what you mean. Actually, I'm just writing a small program, which is an implementation of algorithm solving a problem. So it's clear that what this pointer is used for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It helps to use a typedef for this:

```
typedef int MyArrayType[][5];

MyArrayType * foo(void)
{
    static int arr[5][5];
    return &arr;   // NB: return pointer to 2D array
}
```

If you don't want a use a typedef for some reason, or are just curious about what a naked version of the above function would look like, then the answer is this:

```
int (*foo(void))[][5]
{
    static int arr[5][5];
    return &arr;
}
```

Hopefully you can see why using a typedef is a good idea for such cases.

Comment: maybe it would be `typedef int MyArrayType[5];` instead?

Comment: @ymfoi: well, there is probably more than one way to do this - the above solution works for your specific question, but maybe you are trying to do something different than what you originally asked ? Do you want to return a pointer to a 2D array or not ?

Comment: sorry, I just forgot to type &.. T T

Comment: @PaulR can you tell me the expanded form of typedef?

Comment: No problem - I should probably have highlighted this as it's easy to miss - I'll update the answer.

Comment: @ymfoi: sorry - what do you mean by "expanded form" ?

Comment: @PaulR I mean the form without `typedef`.

Comment: OK - I have added a version without typedef above - please don't write code like this though !

Comment: No problem - for future reference http://cdecl.org/ is a very useful online version of the `cdecl` tool which translates C gibberish <-> English

Comment: In C a function that takes no arguments should be declared with a void parameter list, e.g. `int foo(void)`. A function with *no* arguments, e.g. `int foo()`, is a function that can take *any number* of arguments. Do not use this form if you want your code to be robust.

Comment: @PaulR Where can I find the standard which teaches me how to define some complex types?

Comment: Read Kernighan & Ritchie: http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628 and use the http://cdecl.org tool

Comment: Oh, gotcha! To be honest, I'm writing c-style c++, do not aware of that.

Comment: You need to be aware of the subtle but important differences between C and C++ - they are very different languages in many respects, but for basic POD types such as the above then you can mostly treat them as being similar.

Comment: That is *HORRIBLE* type syntax. I thought I knew C.

Answer (score 24):

The return type would be `int (*)[5]` (pointer to 5-element array of `int`), as follows

```
int (*foo(void))[5]
{
  static int arr[5][5];
  ...
  return arr;
}
```

It breaks down as

```
      foo             -- foo
      foo(    )       -- is a function
      foo(void)       --   taking no parameters
     *foo(void)       -- returning a pointer
    (*foo(void))[5]   --   to a 5-element array       
int (*foo(void))[5]   --   of int
```

Remember that in most contexts, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted to type "pointer to `T`".  The type of the expression `arr` is "5-element array of 5-element arrays of `int`", so it's converted to "pointer to 5-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[5]`.

Comment: Thank you for painting a thin layer of sanity on top of this atrocity that is C syntax.

Comment: C declaration syntax is actually fairly straightforward once you learn the basic rules.  Ugly, but straightforward.  If `(*a)[5]` is a pointer to an array, then `(*f())[5]` is a function returning a pointer to an array.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `int (*foo(void))[5][5]`?

Comment: @MustSeeMelons: That would be the case if we returned `&arr`, but we're not.  The *expression* `arr` decays from type "5-element array of 5-element array of `int`" to "pointer to 5-element array of `int`".