# returning 2d array in C…

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a total noob in C. I can't make the connect between this function and main. I'm trying to print out a 2d array and I keep getting segmentation fault. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: When I changed the last line 'printf("%d:[%s]\n",i,*(p+i))' from %s to %c, I get the first word in the file i'm reading from. So turns out that something is in fact being returned from my function. Now just need to figure out how to get it to return words from other lines in the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define num_strings 20
#define size_strings 20

int *read_file(){
    int j = 0;
    static char text[num_strings][size_strings];

    FILE *fp;
    int x;

    fp = fopen("dictionary2.txt", "r");

    char s[100];
    while(!feof(fp)) {
        x = fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]",s);
        fgetc(fp);

        if (x==1) {
            strcpy(text[j],s);
            j++;
        }
    }
    return text;
}

int main() {
    int *p;
    p = read_file();
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d:[%s]\n",i,*(p+i));
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This has got to be the weirdest C code I've ever seen.

Comment: ;} looks like an emoticon of some kind

Comment: You can't return arrays in C, period. Since it's declared `static`, the best you could do is return a suitable pointer to it. Far better is to declare it in `main()`, and pass it into your function, and forget about returning it altogether. Check the return from `fopen()` in case it failed, and don't cast the return from `malloc()`. Learn to format your code properly, too.

Comment: I have code in there to check in case fopen() fails. I took it out for purposes of posting only what I am concerned about here, which is accessing this 2d array.

Comment: `char *s=(char*)malloc(100);` : memory leak. change to `char s[100];`

Comment: Try changing the function return type (and the type of `p` in main) to `char (*)[20]` (pointer to arrays of 20 chars).  As for how to return that, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10794825/929459

Comment: Now it's printing nonsensical characters.

Comment: @Gustav: I've attempted to format your code to make it a bit more sane looking. For the sake of readers, please put only one statement on each line. Also, note that `#define` statements are not scoped. They run until the end of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should be creating your array in `main()` and passing it in, this kind of behavior is very unorthodox. However, if you do insist on doing it this way, you have to return a pointer to your array, since you cannot return arrays in C.

This is the kind of thing you'll need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define num_strings 20
#define size_strings 20

typedef char (*PARR)[num_strings][size_strings];

PARR read_file(int * wordsread)
{
    static char text[num_strings][size_strings];
    FILE *fp;

    if ( (fp = fopen("dictionary2.txt", "r")) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file for reading\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char s[100];
    int j = 0;

    while ( j < num_strings && fgets(s, sizeof s, fp) ) {
        const size_t sl = strlen(s);
        if ( s[sl - 1] == '\n' ) {
            s[sl - 1] = 0;
        }

        if ( (strlen(s) + 1) > size_strings ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "String [%s] too long!\n", s);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        strcpy(text[j++], s);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    *wordsread = j;
    return &text;
}

int main(void)
{
    int wordsread = 0;
    PARR p = read_file(&wordsread);

    for ( int i = 0; i < wordsread; ++i ) {
        printf("%d:[%s]\n", i, (*p)[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which, with a suitable input file, outputs:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./twoarr
0:[these]
1:[are]
2:[some]
3:[words]
4:[and]
5:[here]
6:[are]
7:[some]
8:[more]
9:[the]
10:[total]
11:[number]
12:[of]
13:[words]
14:[in]
15:[this]
16:[file]
17:[is]
18:[twenty]
19:[s'right]
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Note this only works because you declared your array in `read_file()` as `static` - don't return pointers to local variables with automatic storage duration in this way.

Comment: If I could Vote Up a thousand times here I would THANK YOU!!

Comment: I'll settle for a single upvote and an acceptance, if it's what you were looking for and you're inclined to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `#define`s back and changing your function header to return a pointer to arrays of `size_strings` characters, as follows:

```
    #define num_strings 20
    #define size_strings 20

    char (*read_file())[size_strings] {
```

Or alternately, with a typedef:

```
    #define num_strings 20
    #define size_strings 20

    typedef char (*PCharArr)[size_strings];

    PCharArr read_file() {
```

...and change the type of `p` in main accordingly:

```
    char (*p)[size_strings];
```

That will return (a pointer to the first element of) an array of character arrays, which is more or less equivalent to a 2D array of `char`.

Answer (score -1):

Update, oh I see, you pasted the code from main to the function, I know what happened here, you assumed p[20][20] is the same as a p* or maybe a p**, that's not correct, since now if you do *(p+1), the compiler doesn't know each element in p is 20 wide instead of 1 wide.  You approach here should be to declare a pointer to an array of strings in read_file and return that instead:

```
static char text[num_strings][size_strings];
static char *texts[num_strings]

...
while....
    ....
       if (x==1)
        {strcpy(text[j],s);texts[j]=text[j];j++;}


return texts;
```

your p should be char* not int*.  You also need to terminate the loop if 20 items have been read in.

Comment: Yes i'll get to editing the format later. For now, I just want it to WORK. The txt file it is reading is small and the space I allotted is sufficient. 

I'm trying to return a pointer to the function. I wrote the code all inside main() and it worked. But my goal here is to be able to call it from a function.

Comment: I'll take a look, but code is working now anyway. Thanks for the time and effort, much appreciated.