# variable 2d array of char* as return value in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having trouble trying to allocate a 2d array of char* and return it from a function.

```
//my return type needs to change to something like (char*)[]?
char **readData( size_t numRows, size_t numCols )
{
    //I think this needs to chage to something like this:
    //char* (*data)[numRows] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numCols );
    char **data = malloc( sizeof(char*) * numRows * numCols );

    for( size_t r=0; r < numRows; ++r ) {
        for(size_t c=0; c < numCols; ++c) {     
            data[r*numRows+c] = strdup( getString() );

            //I'd like this to be:
            //data[r][c] = strndup( getString() );
        }
    }

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    size_t rows = 5;
    size_t cols = 7;
    char **data = readData( rows, cols );

    if( data != NULL ) {

        for( int r=0; r < rows; ++r ) {
            for( int c=0; c < cols; ++c ) {
                printf( "[%i][%i] = %s\n", r, c, data[r*rows+c] );
                free(data[r*rows+c]);
                data[r*rows+c] = NULL;

                //I'd really like this to be:
                //printf( "[%i][%i] = %s\n", r, c, data[r][c] );
                //free(data[r][c]);
                //data[r][c] = NULL;
            }
        }

        free(data);
        data = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

1) The above code is broken somehow. The printf prints NULLs when I wouldn't expect it to. I must be screwing up the indexing someplace.

2) I believe with C99 I can use the more familiar `data[][]` notation to index the 2d array of pointers. I have the changes in comments in the above code but I don't know what to set the return type of the function as. How can I change my program to use the `data[][]` notation? It may not be possible since I do not know either array dimension at compile time.

I've looked at the following stack overflow questions but still can't seem to get my head around it:
[Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)

[How to return a two-dimensional pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794825/how-to-return-a-two-dimensional-pointer-in-c)

[Why can't we use double pointer to represent two dimensional arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470950/why-cant-we-use-double-pointer-to-represent-two-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: There is no 2D array.

Comment: **Always** check the result of functions which can encounter an error!

Comment: @Olaf I agree! When writing production code check the return values of everything. For prototype code posted on the internet, checking returns just makes it hard to read.

Comment: Nonsense, especially as you have a problem with your code, you shall check the results. What if exactly **this** is the problem?

Comment: And what do you mean with "`data[][]`" notation? You still cannot dereference a pointer to an inclomplete type and as function argument, it still decays to a pointer.

Comment: As I see it, most of the OPs are students,  if nothing is said about the lack of checking for errors, then the OP will go merrily on their way, thinking it is 'ok' to not check for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a two-dimensional grid of strings, so your data structure is `char ***`. The data on all levels is dynamically allocated.

`data` is a handle to a dynamic array of `numRows` rows. Each row `data[r]` is a handle to a dynamic array of `numCols` strings; these arrays must also be allocated explicitly. Each string `data[r][c]` is a handle to a dynamic array of chars, which you create via `strdup`.

So your code might look like:

```
char ***readData(size_t numRows, size_t numCols)
{
    char ***data = malloc(numRows * sizeof(*data));

    for (size_t r=0; r < numRows; ++r) {
        data[r] = malloc(numCols * sizeof(*data[r]));

        for(size_t c=0; c < numCols; ++c) {     
            data[r][c] = strdup(getString());
        }
    }

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    size_t rows = 5;
    size_t cols = 7;
    char ***data = readData(rows, cols);

    if (data != NULL) {
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
                printf("[%i][%i] = \"%s\"\n", r, c, data[r][c]);
                free(data[r][c]);
            }
            free(data[r]);
        }
        free(data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense.

Comment: There is no 2D "grid of strings" (whatever that would be). A pointer is not an array. As mush as a `_Complex` is not a `_Bool`.

Comment: @Olaf. Super comment, really. The grid of strings is the use case: The OP wants to have a 7x5 matrix of strings. Please distinguish between domain and implementation language. And nowhere do I say that a pointer is an array.

Answer (score -1):

the following code implements a 2D array of numRows x numCols

You will need to add the error checking (returned value !=NULL) after each call to `malloc()` to assure the operation was successful.

It initially clears all the pointers so it will be easy to pass each pointer to `free()` without worrying about if the pointer actually contains a valid pointer  (`free()` properly handles a NULL pointer)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * getString( void );

//my return type needs to change to something like (char*)[]?
char **readData( size_t numRows, size_t numCols )
{
    // following results in an array of pointers to char, 1 ptr per row
    char **data = malloc( sizeof(char*) * numRows );

    // set all row pointers to NULL, to make it easier to free all the allocations
    memset( data, 0x00, sizeof( char*) *numRows );

    for( size_t r=0; r<numRows; r++)
    { // for each row
        data[r] = malloc( sizeof( char *) * numCols) ;
        // set all column ptrs to NULL, to kame it easier to free all the allocations
        memset( data[r], 0x00, sizeof( char * ) * numCols) ;
    }


    // set all the column pointers in each row
    for( size_t r=0; r < numRows; ++r )
    {
        for(size_t c=0; c < numCols; ++c)
        {
            char ** pRow = data+r; // get ptr to row entry
            char ** pCol = pRow+c;    // get ptr to column entry
            *pCol = strdup( getString() );
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: This line `data[r][c] = strdup( getString() )` assigns a `char *` to a `char`, or at least tries.

Comment: I fixed the code, including a couple of compile problems